# Reference Requests: The Turaev-Viro model and Topological QFT's

Tags: resource-recommendations, topological-field-theory, category-theory

I've been inspired by the string-net condensation paper by Levin and Wen (see [here](http://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/0404617)) to learn about the [Turaev-Viro model](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Turaev-Viro+model) and its relationship to topological QFTs. Any references that could be helpful for accomplishing that would be very welcome. While I'm at it, pedagogical reviews/introductions to topological QFTs would be useful as well. Textbook and paper recommendations are both welcome.

I should also mention that I'm definitely not a mathematician. I'm familiar with the details of non-abelian gauge quantization, and with it the basics of representation theory. I've also made some progress learning about CFTs from the big yellow book (di Francesco et al.). But beyond that, my pure math background is a bit limited, so physically motivated arguments would be most immediately useful to me. But, if you're aware of good sources for learning about relevant math topics, that would be useful as well.

Comment: Not sure if it counts as an introduction, but the beginning of the story of topological field theory (in the sense of Reshetikhin-Turaev) is probably Witten's paper "Quantum Field Theory and the Jones Polynomial" (available here https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.cmp/1104178138). Later papers on the subject (for example, the one by Reshetikhin and Turaev themselves) sometimes read more like math than physics. However, it may be necessary to learn these pieces from (higher) category theory at some point anyway...

Answer (score 1):

- Turaev has a [new book](http://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783319498331) on exactly this.
- Turaev also has a [slightly older book](https://www.degruyter.com/view/product/461906) that has overlapping material on TQFTs